# How to declare in stored procedure that a row does not exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if a certain `QuestionID` and `EmployeeID` exist; if they do, they need to be inserted like here below (that's working fine).

But if they don't exist, I want a good error for the user, so that he knows that the `QuestionID` or the `EmployeeID` or both do not exist. Also maybe a rollback of the transaction? Now I can add every number, but the stored procedure still completed the commands...

I have this code (I'm using SQL Server):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Contentment
    @employeeID INT,
    @questionid INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT questionid 
               FROM question 
               WHERE questionid = @questionid)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT employeeID 
                   FROM employee 
                   WHERE employeeid = @employeeID)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO contentment (employeeid, questionid, date, score, comment)
            VALUES (@employeeID, @questionid, null, null, null)
        END
        ELSE
            IF @employeeID = 0
                RAISERROR ('-certain error-', 16, 1, @employeeid) 

    IF @questionid = 0
        RAISERROR ('-certain error-', 16, 1, @questionid)           
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to do it like this - check for the existence of *both* parameters in a single statement - if not, then provide an error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Contentment
    @employeeID INT,
    @questionid INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- check for *both* conditions at once
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.question WHERE questionid = @questionid) AND
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.employee WHERE employeeid = @employeeID)
    BEGIN
        -- if OK --> insert
        INSERT INTO dbo.contentment (employeeid, questionid, date, score, comment)
        VALUES (@employeeID, @questionid, null, null, null)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- if NOT OK --> provide error
        RAISERROR ('@EmployeeID or @QuestionID do not exist', 16, 1, null) 
    END
END
```

> *Also maybe a rollback of the transaction?*

Since you're not really doing anything (no `INSERT` happening in either of the two ID's doesn't exist), there's really no transaction to roll back at this point....

Answer (score 0):

you can use an error message parameter like that :

```
  CREATE PROC  dbo.Usp_Contentment 
    AS  
begin
         declare @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(MAX)  = ''
         IF not exists (select 1 from dbo.Question where QuestionId= @QuestionId)
           set @ErrMsg = 'Some msg'
         if not exists (select 1 from dbo.Employee where Employee Id= @EmployeeId)
           set @ErrMsg =@ErrMsg + 'some msg'

         IF @msg=''
           INSERT INTO dbo.contentment (employeeid, questionid, date, score, comment)
            VALUES (@employeeID, @questionid, null, null, null)
         else 
           RAISERROR(@ErrMsg,16,1)
end
```

don't use ROLLBACK because you handled the NULL Values

Comment: Could you maybe explain what you are doing with 'set @ErrMsg = @ErrMsg'? And with 'if @msg='') Thanks.

Comment: error message parameter's initial value is blank , if the first select was not exits  fill parameter's  with some message like 'could not find this question'  if found question the parameter's value is still blank , then if could not find both of Question and Employee  parameter will be somethings like this :'could not find Question' + 'could not find Employee' and after that if parameter is still blank , that means everything is ok and ready for insert

Comment: Thanks, but if@MSG has to be @ErrMsg isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would let the database do the work.  Declare the table to have proper foreign key relationships:

```
alter table contentment add constraint fk_conententment_question
    foreign key (questionid) references question(questionid);

alter table contentment add constraint fk_conententment_employee
    foreign key (employeeid) references employee(employeeid);
```

Then write the procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Contentment (
    @employeeID INT,
    @questionid INT
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.contentment (employeeid, questionid, date, score, comment)
        VALUES (@employeeID, @questionid, null, null, null)
END;  -- usp_Contentment
```

The *database* will generate an error that the foreign key relationship fails -- if there is no matching key.

This approach is much better than doing the test yourself for several reasons:

- The database ensures the data integrity, so you know the relationships are maintained regardless of where the data changes occur.
- The integrity applies to both `insert`s and `update`s.  There is no need to put checks in multiple places.
- The integrity check is thread-safe, so if rows are being modified in the reference tables, the integrity check works.

If you really want a customized message, you can catch the error in a `try`/`catch` block and have a customized error.